# returning boolean on class method

Tags: php

I have a class with a couple of methods

`deleteUploadedFile()` and `currentUploadedFiles()`.

currentUploadedFiles(), basically loops over a session array and displays it on screen, simple as. Code sample:

```
function currentUploadedFiles()
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION['fileArray']) && $this->count > 0)
        {
            echo '<p style="clear:both">Current files uploaded list:</p>';
            echo '<ol>';

            foreach($_SESSION['fileListing'] as $key => $value )
            {
                echo '<li>'. $value .' <a href="'.$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"].'?id='.$key.'">[Remove File]</a></li>';
            }

            echo "</ol>\n\r";
            echo "<p> Current file size allowance: ". $this->_returnRemainingSessionFileSize() ." of 8 MB";
        } else {
            echo '<p style="clear:both">No files have been uploaded yet</p>';
        }    

        if($this->deleteUploadedFile() === true)
        {
            echo '<p>File has now been deleted from our records.</p>';
        }
    }
```

the deleteUploadedFile() method, basically when form is submitted it deletes file from the server and removes the entry from the session array. Sample code:

```
function deleteUploadedFile()
    {
        (int) $id = $_GET['id'];
        (bool) $deleted = false;

        if (file_exists($this->target_path.'/'.$_SESSION['fileArray'][$id]))
        {

            $_SESSION['fileSize'] -= $this->_checkSessionFileSize($id);

            if (unlink($this->target_path.'/'.$_SESSION['fileArray'][$id]))
            {

                $deleted = true; //'<p>File has now been deleted from our records.</p>';
                unset($_SESSION['fileArray'][$id]);
                unset($_SESSION['fileListing'][$id]);


            }

        }

        return $deleted;

    }
```

my controller, basically checks if file id# isset, then checks if the array id# isset, then calls the `deleteUploadedFile()` method and then calls the `currentUploadedFiles()` method.

Question is, why when I var_dump $deleted var in `deleteUploadedFile()` I get bool(true) but inside the `currentUploadedFiles()` method I get bool(false). Sounds like I'm messing up the scope somehow?

Comment: How exactly do you `var_dump` those variables inside you methods?

Comment: @Nicolás - echo  '<pre>'; var_dump($deleted); echo '</pre>'; before the return $deleted; in deleteUploadedFile() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like $deleted is in the local scope of the delete function.

Something like the following should work.

```
class theClass
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->deleted = false
    }

    function delete()
    {
        $this->deleted = true;
    }

    function upload()
    {
        var_dump($this->deleted);
    }

}
```

Comment: @Jared: np. Glad I could help :)